# How to use ASP.NET4.5 Login Form with SQL Membership Provider?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, membership-provider

I'm using the new login control in ASP.NET 4.5 webforms and need to check the username and password against my SQL Membership provider.  I've already setup membership and roles and created my user via the Web Application Tool.

When I try to login, my username and password is not authenticating against the membership provider.  Here are the relevant entries in web.confgi:

```
   <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="WebTrendsConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
      enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
      requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
      applicationName="/" name="DefaultMembershipProvider" 
      type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, 
      Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/"
      name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, 
      System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

UPDATE:  Still cannot login with username and password created in WSAT.  Here's my connectionstring and providers:

```
<connectionStrings>
<remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=PKFDB0;Initial Catalog=WebTrends; 
Integrated Security=False; User ID=*****; Password=******;" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

```
 <membership>
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
      enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
      requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
      applicationName="/" name="DefaultMembershipProvider" 
      type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, 
      Version=1.0.0.0, 
      Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/"
      name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, 
      System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Are you getting any errors or just invalid login?

2: Add  in the providers section of both Membership and Roles:

```
 <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    ......
  </providers>
</membership>
```

3: Make sure you have set the defaultProvider for both Membership and Roles.

4: After making above changes, create a brand new user and try login.

5: **EDIT:** Make sure you don't have an empty structure for Login Authenticate event.

Comment: I receive Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again.

Comment: Check some suggestions here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27682/Your-Login-Attempt-was-not-Successful-Please-Try

Answer (score 2):

Your membership and roleManager should use same connection string, unless you are validating against two databases - user db and role db - which is not common.

```
connectionStringName="WebTrendsConnectionString"

connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"
```

**Updated:** 
Can you explicitly set your application name such as `applicationName="WebTrends"`? Then verify that you can create role and user using [`ASP.Net Configuraton`](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/moving-to-aspnet-20/membership).

[image]

Comment: I updated the answer. Try to create role and user using ASP.Net Config. If you can, your configuration in web.config is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The `Login` control was [added in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), and uses the membership provider by default:

> The Login control uses a membership provider to obtain user credentials. Unless you specify otherwise, the Login control uses the default membership provider defined in the Web.config file. To specify a different provider, set the [MembershipProvider property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.membershipprovider%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to one of the membership provider names defined in your application's Web.config file. For more information, see [Membership Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx3h274z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
>
> If you want to use a custom authentication service, you can use the [OnAuthenticate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.onauthenticate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to call the service.

If you've already set up the membership provider, you should be able to simply add a `Login` control to the page; you won't need any code to validate the login.